# Can we create users via cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create local users on my EC2 instance and pass the public key to enable SSH. It doesn't work when I do it via cloudformation template or from the console (passing the script in User-Date).

But it works when I do it on putty after the instance is launched.

CLoudFormation Template (doesn't create the user)--

```
"UserData" : {
         "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : [
               "", [
                  "#!/bin/bash\n",
                  "adduser webadm\n",
                  "su - webadm\n",
                  "mkdir .ssh\n",
                  "chmod 700 .ssh\n",
                  "cd .ssh\n",
                  "touch authorized_keys\n",
                  "chmod 600 authorized_keys\n",
                  "curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key > authorized_keys\n"
               ]
            ]
         }
        }
        }
```

When doing via console  (doesn't create the user)--

```
#!/bin/bash
adduser webadm
su - webadm
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
cd .ssh
touch authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_keys
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key > authorized_keys
```

Again, this script works when executed from putty after the instance is launched.  Not sure, if it can be done while the instance is being launched using cloudformation or console.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the solution, here it is.

```
"UserData" : {
         "Fn::Base64" : {
            "Fn::Join" : [
               "", [
                  "#!/bin/bash\n",
                  "adduser webadm\n",
                  "su - webadm\n",
                  "/bin/mkdir /home/webadm/.ssh\n",
                  "chmod 700 .ssh\n",
                  "cd .ssh\n",
                  "/bin/touch /home/webadm/.ssh/authorized_keys\n",
                  "chmod 600 authorized_keys\n",
                  "curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key > /home/webadm/.ssh/authorized_keys\n"
               ]
            ]
         }
```

Works like a charm.